# How to group Iterable[String] into (key, no of occurrences) tuple

Tags: scala, pyspark

I am new to spark and scala, I am trying to

I have RDD in the form of (presentation,CompactBuffer(3, 3, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 28, 28, 28))
I am trying to convert into (presentation, List((3,2),(24,5),(28,3))

I am able to convert into the form (string, Iterable[String]) 
(presentation,List((3,1), (3,1), (24,1), (24,1), (24,1), (24,1), (24,1), (28,1), (28,1), (28,1))).

How to group them into (3,2), (24, 3)

```
''' val RDD4 = RDD3.map {
      case (key, values) =>
        val v = values.map(word => (word, 1))
        (key, v)
    }'''
```

Comment: Spark is written in Scala and pyspark is Python API for spark.

Answer (score 0):

you can get so:

```
List((3,1), (3,1), (24,1), (24,1), (24,1), (24,1), (24,1), (28,1), (28,1), (28,1))
    .groupBy{case (key, _) => key}
    .mapValues(
      valuesWithSameKeyList => valuesWithSameKeyList
        .map{ 
          case (_, value) => value
        }.sum
    )
```